# Desktop Compose different borders for BasicTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have `SimpleTextField` with 1px rounded border with different thickness and color on the bottom of it.

I have experimented with `drawLine` but it seems I am missing something essential. Whenever I try to draw a 1px line (at the top in the code bellow), the result is 2px line starting 1px above field and faded color.

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(value: String, onValueChange:(String) -> Unit) {
    
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        singleLine = true,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = Modifier.height(36.dp).width(50.dp).padding(top = 5.dp, start = 2.dp)
        //.border(1.dp, Color(0xFFe1e6ea), RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
        .background(Color.Green)
        .drawBehind {                
            drawLine(
                color = Color.Red,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
                end = Offset(x = size.width, y = 0f),
                strokeWidth = 1f
            )
        },

        textStyle = TextStyle.Default.copy(fontSize = 14.sp),
        decorationBox = {innerTextField ->
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                //.background(Color(0xFFfafcfd), radius)
                .padding(start = 11.dp, end = 11.dp)
            ) {
                innerTextField()
            }
    }

)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple part first: Compose uses a coordinate system with the origin (0,0) at the top left. So in order to draw something at the bottom of your component, you want to use `y = size.height`.

Now for the second part, why is your 1px line actually 2px wide and on top of that the wrong color?

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on rendering engines. 

But what seems to be the case is this:
`drawLine` draws half the line's width to the left and right (or top and bottom), so changing the line's width will make it grow in both directions uniformly. 
That means by drawing a line from let's say (0,0) to (100,0) with a stroke width of 1, you are basically drawing a rectangle with the top-left at (0,-0.5) and bottom-right at (100,0.5)
So we are drawing half a pixel above and another half a pixel below the line.
Here anti-aliasing kicks in and instead of drawing half a pixel at full color, it draws a full pixel at "half" the color, or rather blends it 50/50 with the background. Since that happens both above and below the line, you end up with 2px line at "half" it's color.

How to prevent this? 
It **seems** to help to offset you line's y-coordinates by 0.5, to avoid ending up with a rectangle like above, although I am not sure this is a surefire solution. Alternatively using `drawRect` with a rectangle of 1px height seems to also work.

If you care for a more practical answer:
Don't care about being pixel perfect. I would generally advice against drawing anything with fixed pixel sizes. Instead use `dp` values and if necessary convert them to `px` values on the fly, for example to draw on a `Canvas`